# Media: What are the arguments for using a software license?

Tags: artistic-works

This is somewhat inspired by this: [Does a GPL image “infect” my blog post?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/4408/does-a-gpl-image-infect-my-blog-post) and the [Google Material Design Icons](https://design.google.com/icons/). The latter is a very well known project.

The first question deals with a picture licensed under the GPL. The material design icons hosts a series of icons licensed under the Apache 2.0 license - this was changed a couple weeks ago. It was formerly CC BY.

An image can in no way have a true "Source" or "Object" form, so it feels somewhat awkward. Images just aren't code, which is what the aforementioned licenses primarily cover.

I do have a couple arguments which [I've encountered](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/417#issuecomment-242928357), especially when considering the Material Design Icons:

For:

- It's a more familiar license for developers
- It allows a project to host code related to the project

Against:

- It's not a media focused license
- The terms used may not properly apply to media
- It's not a familiar license for media artists

Am I missing something?

Why is it that so many projects use software licenses for media? What are the arguments for doing so, especially when there are families of dedicated licenses, such as those by Creative Commons?

<sup>Note that I'm in no way questioning the licensing decision made by Google, and I don't want anyone to start anything as a result of this post. Decisions made by people are their own, and should be respected.</sup>

Comment: Did you gather the for and against arguments from any discussion they had about the relicensing?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Yes I did. I can put up a link if people would like (I kind of resisted that initially).

Comment: Well, right now the question reads like you came up with these arguments on your own - I do assume you meant to write "encountered" instead of "countered", though.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Oh oops. I'll fix that :)

Comment: One slight nitpick: an image _could_ have a source form depending on how it was made - eg. a layered PSD vs a flattened PNG or JPEG

Comment: @TimMalone I probably should've expanded on that, but when you see *"Object" form shall mean any form resulting from mechanical transformation or translation of a Source form, including but not limited to compiled object code, generated documentation, and conversions to other media types.* (taken from the Apache 2.0 license), it may not seem to make sense :)

Comment: Aren't traditional bitmap images (png, gif, jpeg) defined using binary code? And aren't image editors just WYSIWYG editors for that code like Dreamweaver might be for HTML/Javascript and Visual Studio might be for C#/XAML?

Comment: @TomDworzanski If that's the case, we might as well consider everyone to be a sequence of bytes, which itself is just a sequence of `1`s and `0`s. The point that I'm trying to relay is that software has a *distinct and distinguishable* editable form (source code), as well as a final, uneditable, compiled form (object). To apply that model to an image, for example, wouldn't work - the image has a single form to our perspective, even if the underlying representation is just bits and bytes.

Comment: @Zizouz212 I don't agree with that. There are just greater levels and lower levels of abstraction (often with many intermediate levels). Some very high level languages compile to lower level languages such as C or JavaScript. Languages like C#, Java, or modern Python compile to an intermediate object code which is binary but not compiled to machine code. Lower level languages like C++ might compile to assembly. Ultimately you get to the "1s and 0s" the computer understands, but you can't just put strict definitions on "source" and "object" code. The terms are strictly relative.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Further, I'm pretty sure images are stored in formats that are distinctly defined (a source form), and that need to be converted to a final form the computer can display. Otherwise there would be only one (lossless) image format.

Comment: @Zizouz212: What you are asserting is ONLY true for photographers (even then, only those that don't work with RAW images). For graphics PSD and AI files are source, JPG and EPS are objects (though EPS is also technically source - Postscript literally is a programming language). Basically what the Material Design license means is that if you derive your icons and sell them as gif your customers have the right to request and re-distribute the SVG or AI files the gif was created from

Comment: This is the source code for the Material Design icons: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/notification/svg/design, this is the intermediate object code: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/notification/svg/production, this is ONE of the final object output: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/notification/1x_web

Answer (score 4):

Use of a software license for media should be discouraged in general but it really depends on how the software license is written. Considerations about specific licenses follow.

## GPL

Section 0 of the GNU GPL 3.0 license contains a definition of "The Program":

> "The Program" refers to any copyrightable work licensed under this
>   License.

and Section 1 defines the "source code":

> The "source code" for a work means the preferred form of the work
>   for making modifications to it.

This explains why the GNU FAQ clearly states that the license can be used for something other than software:

> [**Can I use the GPL for something other than software?**](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#GPLOtherThanSoftware)
>
> You can apply the GPL to any kind of work, as long as it is clear what constitutes the “source code” for the work. The GPL defines this as the preferred form of the work for making changes in it.

In the case of an SVG image, or a PNG image having vectorial source, this license choice can make a lot of sense.

## Apache

What I said for the GPL is even truer for the Apache 2.0 license. Indeed, it contains the following definitions:

> "Source" form shall mean the preferred form for making modifications,
>   including but not limited to software source code, documentation
>   source, and configuration files.
>
> "Object" form shall mean any form resulting from mechanical
>   transformation or translation of a Source form, including but
>   not limited to compiled object code, generated documentation,
>   and conversions to other media types.
>
> "Work" shall mean the work of authorship, whether in Source or
>   Object form, made available under the License, as indicated by a
>   copyright notice that is included in or attached to the work
>   (an example is provided in the Appendix below).

Therefore the Apache license is specifically designed to be applicable beyond software (other media types are even mentioned) whereas the choice of terms throughout the preamble and the rest of the GPL clearly demonstrates that the license was designed for software even though it can still be applied to some other works.

## MIT

On the contrary, the MIT license defines the "Software" as:

> a copy of this software and associated documentation files

Thus the MIT license would lose its meaning completely in case it was applied to media which isn't documentation.

## BSD

The BSD licenses (2 and 3-clause) do not contain any definitions but mention "source code", "binary form" and "THIS SOFTWARE". Thus, similarly to the MIT license, it should not be used for anything else than software.

## Final consideration

Finally if a software contains media, it makes sense to license the whole software, including media, under a software license, but in this case authors would be well advised to dual license the media alone under a Creative Commons license.

Comment: What about Apache? I know I asked about software licenses in general, but most of the time, if I do see media licensed with a software license, it's either Apache or GPL for some reason.

Comment: I edited with more info. Your observation might be explained by the fact that these are two licenses that can indeed by applied to media without problem.

Comment: In the case of the Material Design icons, the source code for the icons actually exist. Real, text, source code: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/notification/svg/design